# VueJS update $data inside directive

Tags: javascript, directive, vuejs2, vue.js

We got a component and directive. Our component data structure looks like this:

```
{
    langs: [
        {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        },
        {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside our directive we would like to update the langs sub-properties dynamic, from our component. The html-form we got for this looks like the form bellow, including our directive.

```
<div v-for="lang in langs">

    <input type="text" v-model="lang.title">

    <textarea v-model="lang.content" v-customdirective="lang.content"></textarea>

</div>
```

Our question: how can we update the v-model property at the component of the directives element?

Comment: Can you add code of v-customdirective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by triggering an event:

```
var event = new Event('input', {bubbles: true})
el.value = 'Test'
el.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the v-customdirective="lang.content" attribute for the textarea element